# Como identificar o elemento filho clicado através do evento click no elemento pai

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ecmascript-6

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
<div class="tipo-cadastro">
    <div class="box-logista active">Logista</div>
    <div class="box-distribuidor">Distribuidor</div>
</div>
```

e o seguinte código em javascript/jQuery:

```
$('.tipo-cadastro').click((e) => {
    $('.tipo-cadastro').find('div').removeClass('active');
    $(e.currentTarget).addClass('active');
});
```

O meu problema é que dentro da minha function `e.currentTarget` corresponde ao elemento pai, ou seja, o elemento que possui o evento `click`.

Eu sei que poderia usar o evento click diretamente em cada elemento filho. Mas gostaria de saber se é possível através do evento click no elemento pai saber qual elemento filho foi clicado?

Comment: Possivel duplicada de http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/138171/129 ou http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/131776/129

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar o `target`:

```js
$('.tipo-cadastro').click((e) => {
  console.log(e.target);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tipo-cadastro">
  <div class="box-logista active">Logista</div>
  <div class="box-distribuidor">Distribuidor</div>
</div>
```